# pyplot inside tkinter opens extra figure with no plots inside

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi all and have a great new year.
I need some help here with my code. 
I have embed the pyplot inside tkinter but every time I call the function, it opens and new empty figure1, figure2 and so on. I have to close the figures at the moment, but while my script runs, each time I need to update the plot,it opens the new empty figures and time passes by with no reason. This is my code so far. Thanks in advance for any help

```
def plot_tour(self, tour_tuples):
    """
        We call this passing the list of tuples with city
        coordinates to plot the tour we want on the GUI
    """
    data_in_array = np.array(tour_tuples)
    transposed = data_in_array.T
    x, y = transposed
    self.f, self.a = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    self.f = Figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=100)
    self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111)
    self.a.plot(x, y, 'ro')
    self.a.plot(x, y, 'b-')
    self.a.set_title('Current best tour')
    self.a.set_xlabel('X axis coordinates')
    self.a.set_ylabel('Y axis coordinates')
    self.a.grid(True)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=root)
    self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

    plt.close('all')
```

So after the proposal of [tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell) the extra figure eliminated. To update thought the plot needed a canvaw.draw() and a canvas.show(). The full code now is as below

```
def plot_tour(self, tour_tuples):
    """
        We call this passing the list of tuples with city
        coordinates to plot the tour we want on the GUI
    """
    data_in_array = np.array(tour_tuples)
    transposed = data_in_array.T
    x, y = transposed
    plt.ion()
    #self.f, self.a = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    self.f = Figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=100)
    self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111, navigate=True)
    self.a.plot(x, y, 'ro')
    self.a.plot(x, y, 'b-')
    self.a.set_title('Current best tour')
    self.a.set_xlabel('X axis coordinates')
    self.a.set_ylabel('Y axis coordinates')
    self.a.grid(True)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=root)
    self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.canvas.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the line

```
self.f, self.a = plt.subplots(1, 1)
```

and it should work correctly.  As you are embedding mpl in a larger application using the OO interface, you don't even need to *import* pyplot.

These [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/index.html) may also be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, I did that but now the plot does not updating.But I added canvas.draw() and canvas.show() and now works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: you will need to manually trigger `draw` when ever you change the axes (changing limits, addidng artists, ect) via user interaction.  Added an extra link.